# User Defined Function in SQL

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I am trying to write a UDF similar to this but it keeps failing the syntax. I keep getting an error near concat.

```
CREATE FUNCTION ParseUserAgentString (@user_agent VARCHAR(200))
RETURNS VARCHAR(400)
RETURN CONCAT( user_agent LIKE "%Chrome%",
    " ",
    user_agent LIKE "%Firefox%",
    " ", 
    user_agent LIKE "%Mozilla%",
    " ", 
    user_agent LIKE "%MSIE%",
    " ",
    user_agent LIKE "%Opera%",
    " ", 
    user_agent LIKE "%Safari%"
    );
```

I get the following error on execution.

````
[SQL: CREATE FUNCTION ParseUserAgentString (user_agent VARCHAR(200))
 RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
 RETURN CONCAT_WS(" ",
     user_agent LIKE "%Chrome%",
     user_agent LIKE "%Firefox%",
     user_agent LIKE "%Mozilla%",
     user_agent LIKE "%MSIE%",
     user_agent LIKE "%Opera%",
     user_agent LIKE "%Safari%"
     );]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/biGrF.png
````

Comment: If you are getting an error please it include it the question. Its very relevant information.

Comment: `@user_agent` should be `user_agent`.

Comment: BTW, you can use `CONCAT_WS()` if you're using the same delimiter between all the values.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for that suggestion i am trying to replicate something in BigQuery and BigQuery doesn't support CONCAT_WS.

Comment: Also, @user_agent is not working nor is user_agent

Comment: You're creating a [Stored Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-routines-syntax.html). MySQL uses the term [User-Defined Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-udf.html) for a C/C++ module you compile and load into the server as a dynamic library.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a session variable as a function parameter, `@user_agent` should be just `user_agent`.

The `VARCHAR` datatype requires a length.

```
CREATE FUNCTION ParseUserAgentString (user_agent VARCHAR(200))
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
RETURN CONCAT_WS(" ",
    user_agent LIKE "%Chrome%",
    user_agent LIKE "%Firefox%",
    user_agent LIKE "%Mozilla%",
    user_agent LIKE "%MSIE%",
    user_agent LIKE "%Opera%",
    user_agent LIKE "%Safari%"
    );
```

Comment: I keep getting this error ```sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "FUNCTION": syntax error```

Comment: Why are you getting a sqlite3 error if you're using MySQL (according to the tag on the question)?